# How to prompt for some information from PAM module

Tags: authentication, module, pam, pluggable

I'm writing a Plug-gable authentication module for ssh. I am looking for prompting for some extra information after user name and password verification but before giving access to user. Can anyone suggest how should I do this.

Actually after SSH I want to extend the same for some other services. So I am looking at some PAM module level suggestion.

[EDIT] Solution :
I have used conversation function provided by PAM. It is used to communicate between PAM aware application and module.

Thanks,
GG

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at keyboard-interactive ssh authentication method it is designed for such cases.

For OpenSSh you should enable PAMAuthenticationViaKbdInt, ChallengeResponseAuthentication and UsePAM in sshd_config.

Didn't tried it though, hope it will help.

Comment: Actually after SSH I want to extend the same for some other services. So I am looking at some PAM level suggestion. Sorry for incomplete question.

Comment: OK, I clearly am on the wrong side of the answer. Thanks for clarifying.